# How i can rotate a custom markers in Leaflet for PDF (in website works)

Tags: javascript, php, promise, leaflet, pdfmake

i work on create a PDF from Leaflet map with custom icons, and I rotate these icons to angle for track report(cars).
I use leaflet-image plugin to create the image from map and then I use pdfmake to add the image to PDF (PDF contains map, table and canvas JS charts).
Everything works fine (the markers rotate on website) but when I add map image to my PDF the markers don't have a rotation.

> I add the image with rotation with these code

```
var marker=[
  <?php foreach($track as $key => $value){ ?>L.marker([
  <?php echo $value['Y']; ?>,
  <?php echo $value['X']; ?>],{icon: icon
  <?php echo $value['Eng']; ?>, rotationAngle: 
  <?php echo $value['Angle']; ?> }).bindPopup("
  <?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $key); ?> / speed: 
  <?php echo $value['Speed']; ?> km/h." ),
  <?php } ?>
<?php ?>]
```

I was looking for other libraries that can solve my problem.

> I get the image with these code

```
 var icon3 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/direction_green.png',
    iconSize:     [12, 12],
    iconAnchor:   [0, 0],
    popupAnchor:  [15, -8]
    });

    var icon2 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/stop_green.png',
    iconSize:     [12, 12],
    iconAnchor:   [0, 0],
    popupAnchor:  [15, -8]
    });

    var icon1 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/stop_blue.png',
    iconSize:     [12, 12], 
    iconAnchor:   [0, 0],
    popupAnchor:  [15, -8]
    });

    var icon0 = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'images/stop_black.png',
    iconSize:     [12, 12],
    iconAnchor:   [0, 0],
    popupAnchor:  [15, -8]
    });
```

Then I use the corresponding status marker for the car (engine onn, engine off, etc...)

I see the problem is this rotation is the html rotation.
Can i rotate the image with js/jQuery before add to my map?
I get the image with:

```
iconUrl: 'images/stop_black.png
```

I have one more problem:
I do not have the circles and the line in my PDF.
In website everything in fine again.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the problem browser-dependent? Assuming you're using `Leaflet.rotatedMarker.js`, it needs <transform-function> support in the browser. Also pdfmake has some browser dependencies.

Comment: No, it's not browser problem. The problem is these leaflat-image plugin does't rotate the markers.

Comment: .... and that might be because the browser lacks the necessary support. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer for my question.
I hope to help someone.
The plugin leaflat-rotate-marker use css to rotate the markers and when i use plugin leaflat-image to create the image from map the markers in PDF don't have a rotation becouse leaflat image don't work with html and css.
My compleate code is this:

```
processArray(js_tracks); //call processArray with my array

async function processArray(array) {
    shelterMarkers.eachLayer(function(layer){ //remove previous markers because i call this function onload and on map zoomed.  
        mymap.removeLayer(layer);
    });

    for (let item of array) {
        if(icontmp[item['Reakt']][item['Angle']] != -1){ //array icontmp is my cash for previous created markers.
            var iUrl = icontmp[item['Reakt']][item['Angle']];
        }
        else{ // if i don't have cashed markers with same angel await for delayedLog where i rotate the markers by angle and specific condition (item['Reakt'])
            icontmp[item['Reakt']][item['Angle']] = await delayedLog(item['Angle'], item['Reakt']);
            var iUrl = icontmp[item['Reakt']][item['Angle']];           
        }

        var ico = L.icon({ //create a object with marker
            iconUrl: iUrl,
            iconSize: [(4.5*(mymap.getZoom()))/2, (4.5*(mymap.getZoom()))/2], // resize by map zoom
            iconAnchor: [15, 15],
            popupAnchor: [-10, -10]
        });

        L.marker([item['Y'], item['X']], // add X and Y cordinats
        {icon: ico})
        .bindPopup("<p>Време: "+item['dateTime']+" </p><p> скорост: "+item['Speed']+" км/ч.</p><p> Реакция: "+item['Reaktion']+" </p><p> "+item['Engine']+" </p>" ).addTo(shelterMarkers); // add to shelterMarkers
    }
    shelterMarkers.addTo(mymap); // add to map when ready
}


function delayedLog(angles, reak){
     if(reak == 0){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/stop_blue.png';
     }
     else if(reak == 1){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/stop_green.png';
     }
     else if(reak == 2){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/direction_green.png';
     }
     else if(reak == 3){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/stop_red.png';
     } 
     else if(reak == 4){
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/direction_red.png';
     }
     else{
         var imgs = '<?php echo base_url();?>/images/stop_black.png';
     }

    var image = loadImage(imgs).then(function (img) { //there i wait for load a image resource. Without it sometimes loading an empty blank instead of a finished image. loadImage is a function from plugin image-promise.min.js

        let canvass = document.createElement('canvas');
        let context = canvass.getContext('2d');
        canvass.width = 50;
        canvass.height = 50;
        context.translate(15, 15);
        context.rotate(angles*Math.PI/180); //rotate by angle
        context.translate(-15, -15);
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        return canvass.toDataURL(); // when ready return dataurl
    })
    return image; // return dataurl to processArray
}
```